# Unable to understand this assembly x86 code

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, openssl, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I am confused why "sub_18054DFD0" function use the address of "crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c" as a parameter but not using it.(
"crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c" is a file in the openssl api library.)

I want to figure out did it call the function in the rsa_ossl library?

```
.text:00000001805BF4E7 loc_1805BF4E7:                          ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0000000180902990o
.text:00000001805BF4E7                                         ; .rdata:00000001809029A0o ...
.text:00000001805BF4E7                 mov     [rsp+28h+arg_50], r15
.text:00000001805BF4EF                 call    sub_1805AF500   ; STR: "crypto\bn\bn_ctx.c"
.text:00000001805BF4F4                 mov     rcx, rsi
.text:00000001805BF4F7                 call    sub_1805AF3D0   ; STR: "crypto\bn\bn_ctx.c"
.text:00000001805BF4FC                 mov     rcx, rsi
.text:00000001805BF4FF                 mov     r15, rax
.text:00000001805BF502                 call    sub_1805AF3D0   ; STR: "crypto\bn\bn_ctx.c"
.text:00000001805BF507                 mov     rcx, [rbx+18h]
.text:00000001805BF50B                 mov     rdi, rax
.text:00000001805BF50E                 call    sub_1805614B0
.text:00000001805BF513                 add     eax, 7
.text:00000001805BF516                 mov     r8d, 100h
.text:00000001805BF51C                 cdq
.text:00000001805BF51D                 and     edx, 7
.text:00000001805BF520                 add     eax, edx
.text:00000001805BF522                 lea     rdx, aCryptoRsaRsa_o ; "crypto\\rsa\\rsa_ossl.c"
.text:00000001805BF529                 sar     eax, 3
.text:00000001805BF52C                 movsxd  rbp, eax
.text:00000001805BF52F                 mov     rcx, rbp
.text:00000001805BF532                 call    sub_18054DFD0
```

Step in the function "sub_18054DFD0":

```
.text:000000018054DFD0 sub_18054DFD0   proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_1804FE630+42Ap
.text:000000018054DFD0                                         ; sub_1804FFAE0+AAp ...
.text:000000018054DFD0                 mov     eax, 28h
.text:000000018054DFD5                 call    sub_180670B80
.text:000000018054DFDA                 sub     rsp, rax
.text:000000018054DFDD                 mov     rax, cs:off_18091E640
.text:000000018054DFE4                 test    rax, rax
.text:000000018054DFE7                 jz      short loc_18054DFFC
.text:000000018054DFE9                 lea     r9, sub_18054DFD0
.text:000000018054DFF0                 cmp     rax, r9
.text:000000018054DFF3                 jz      short loc_18054DFFC
.text:000000018054DFF5                 add     rsp, 28h
.text:000000018054DFF9                 jmp     rax
.text:000000018054DFFC ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:000000018054DFFC
.text:000000018054DFFC loc_18054DFFC:                          ; CODE XREF: sub_18054DFD0+17j
.text:000000018054DFFC                                         ; sub_18054DFD0+23j
.text:000000018054DFFC                 test    rcx, rcx
.text:000000018054DFFF                 jnz     short loc_18054E008
.text:000000018054E001                 xor     eax, eax
.text:000000018054E003                 add     rsp, 28h
.text:000000018054E007                 retn
.text:000000018054E008 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:000000018054E008
.text:000000018054E008 loc_18054E008:                          ; CODE XREF: sub_18054DFD0+2Fj
.text:000000018054E008                 mov     cs:dword_18091E638, 0
.text:000000018054E012                 add     rsp, 28h
.text:000000018054E016                 jmp     j_malloc_0
.text:000000018054E016 sub_18054DFD0   endp ; sp-analysis failed
```

Compiler: MSVC

Architecture：x86-64bit

The file is a mixed DLL and this part is C++ code.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's an argument for [`CRYPTO_malloc`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/mem.c#L165)**

As it's easy to see, this function will pass its arguments to `malloc_impl` if not itself or, otherwise, fallback to `malloc`.
OpenSSL (and its forks, like BoringSSL) use this indirection to enhance `malloc`, see [this](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/STYLE.md)

The string *crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c* is *where* the function in your *first* block of code comes from.
Since OpenSSL is opensource and there is source file name information, it's pretty easy to pinpoint the code you are looking at:

It's [inside `rsa_ossl_private_encrypt`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c#L263) that is defined, of course, in *crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c*.

It's a spot on because there are three calls to "BN functions" (a big numbers facility, I guess), two of which identical, and a call to a "memory allocation function".
One may be thrown off by the calculations of the memory to allocate, particularly one may search for the constants but, as the source shows, they are done by an inlined macro [BN_num_bytes](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/5d8b3a3ef2941b8822523742a0408ca6896aa65d/include/openssl/bn.h#L189) and thus, searching for those constants (i.e. 256, 7, 8 and all their other numerals) won't give anything.

As you can see, the function at `sub_18054DFD0` is `OPENSSL_malloc` and it takes only one parameter.

`OPENSSL_malloc` will pass `OPENSSL_FILE` (which, [as this doc pod says, it's just an alias for `__FILE__`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/79c44b4e3044aee9dc9618850d4f1ce067757b4b/doc/man3/OPENSSL_FILE.pod#L13)) as the second parameter of `CRYPTO_malloc`.
It also passes the line number as the third parameter, in your case it's 256 (the value of `r8d`). My manual analysis found the call a few lines below, which may be due to a different version.

These memory allocations routines keep tracks of the file and line numbers of the allocations callers to ease the debug of memory leaks and corrupts.
Without a tool like Valgrind or DrMemory (for Windows) it's really really hard to pinpoint bug due to memory corruption, so this makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't take a serious look at OpenSSL...So what you mean is this code segment "loc_1805BF4E7" is actually "rsa_ossl_private_encrypt" function in crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c. Did I get it wrong?Then  I can't understand why does assembly code display calls to an API library function in this way rather than display "call  rsa_ossl_private_encrypt" and point the function to an import function. (I am new to reverse engineering, please forgive me if this question is silly). Thanks!

Comment: @Jenny Those are OpenSSL internal functions, even if the library is compiled as DLL they would not be exported unless the programmed marked them so. Once compiled a library loses all its source, including variable and function names. Only the exported function would retain a name (not always and not always the one in the source) but these are internal functions. BTW, you can try finding (or generating) a FLIRT signature or the debug symbols for your OpenSSL version if you want IDA to recognize all the function names.

Answer (score 2):

`sub_18054DFD0` appears to be a memory allocation call. It will use a default function (`j_malloc_0`) if an override function has not been specified in the `cs:off_18091E640` memory location.

The upper block of code will load this value, check if it is not NULL, check if it points back to this function (`cs:off_18091E640`, which would create a never-ending recursive call), then calls the override.

If either of the override checks fail (no override, or circular reference), the memory allocation size is checked for 0. If it is, an immediate `nullptr` is returned, otherwise flow passes to `j_malloc_0`.

Either the override function, or `j_malloc_0`, can make use of the `edx` register value (probably as part of allocation diagnostics).

Comment: It shows that cs:off_18091E640 point back to the function sub_18054DFD0 , so it would call a nerver-ending recursive call then call j_malloc_0 as you said.But I am still confused that j_malloc_0 is encapsulation of the malloc function and what actually did this sub_18054DFD0  function done?Will it called the encrypt function in the c file ?